# Running mac os x application as a user does not stop by its own

Tags: bash, macos, launchd, launch-daemon

I am creating a macOS installer package.

For this I am using a post-install script file that launches an application and then loads a LaunchDaemon plist.

Here is the post-install script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/TestApp
USER_NAME=$(who | head -1 | head -1 | awk '{print $1;}')
sudo -u $USER_NAME /usr/local/TestApp/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test -l

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.testapp.plist
```

The result is that it starts the application with the `sudo -u $USER_NAME /usr/local/TestApp/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test -l` command and then *blocks*, because the application keeps running.

Therefore, the script gets stuck, and the LaunchDaemon is never loaded.

Please let me know what I can do this in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to launch a Mac application (`*.app`) *asynchronously*,

- use `open -a` with the *bundle* directory path (ending in `.app`)
- and pass any pass-through command-line arguments after `--args` (see `man open`):

```
sudo -u $USER_NAME open -a /usr/local/TestApp/Test.app --args -l
```

<sup>See note at the bottom re reliably determining `$USER_NAME`, the invoking user's username.</sup>

If, for some reason, you do need to target the executable embedded in the `*.app` bundle *directly*, you must use Bash's `&` control operator to run the command in the *background*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the underlying username (see comments below).
userName="${HOME##*/}"

# Launch the app in the background, using control operator `&`
# which prevents the command from blocking.
# (Given that the installer runs the script as the root user,
# `sudo` is only needed here for impersonation.)
sudo -u "$userName" /usr/local/TestApp/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/Test -l &

# Load the daemon.
# (Given that the installer runs the script as the root user,
# `sudo` is not needed here.)
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.testapp.plist
```

Note that I've changed the way that the underlying username is determined:

- `${HOME##*/}` extracts the last path component from `$HOME`, the underlying user's home directory path, which reflects the user who invoked the installer.
- This is more robust than using `who` without arguments, whose output can include *other* users.

(As an aside,  `who | head -1 | head -1 | awk '{print $1;}'` can be simplified to the more efficient `who | awk '{print $1; exit}`).

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.